# Getting error in Visual studio 2010 while adding entity data model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error while adding entity data model using visual studio 2010.

> Error:
>
> couldn't resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework version-v4.0'.This can happen if the target Framework is not installed or the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.

I found some post regarding this problem but those unable to resolve this error.In one post there is written to reduce path length.I did that i put my project in side c drive(`i.e-C:\ASP project\Registration`) but still error was there.In another post there was instruction to go project menu of Visual studio then properties and there to add target framework.When i followed this step it asked me to install .NETFramework 4.0 i did this but couldn't resolve this error.So please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you try a Clean/Re-Build?

Comment: @ CaledB : No,How i will do this.I had done only repair .NETFramework version 4.0 after downloading but still error was there.

Comment: Load your project and under the Build Tab "Clean Solution" And "Re-Build Solution" This will remove all exes and compiled files and re-create them.

Comment: @ calebB : First i did clean solution and then rebuild solution.But the error is remain same.But when i did Re-Build Solution in out put section it is giving me following error.

`Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Controllers' does not exist in the namespace 'Registration' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\ASP project\Registration\Registration.Tests\Controllers\HomeControllerTest.`